# What is the difference between: "two-day" and "two days"

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know which would be the correct form:

> - a major two-day auction
> - a major two days auction

The duration of the auction is two days. Which form is the right one to use?

Answer (score 3):

First variant is OK, the second is almost OK (the apostrophe is absent):

> "a major two-day auction"

"Two-day" is an adjective here, written as one word.

> "a major two days' auction"

" two days' " is a possessive form ("an auction of two days").

First variant is more common to use.

Comment: Does 'almost OK' mean you get let off with a grammar police warning?

Comment: By "almost ok" I meant the apostrophe was omitted, edited to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

two days refers to the number of days
two-day refers to the duration of something
If you are French, think about the difference between jour and journee.